# How to make a direct phone call with flutterflow?

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I know direct phone call feature is not there in flutterflow. To make a direct phone call we have to write custom code, and i have written that code and also added the required dependency but still it is not working. Please help me..

**Here is my code**

```
`import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';

    Future<void> phoneCallAction() async {
      const number = '1234567890'; //set the number here
      await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(number);
    }`
```

**This is Pubspec dependency.**

```
flutter_phone_direct_caller: ^2.1.1
```

Comment: Have you added the permissions?